# Angularjs 1.X equivalent to Angular 2 HostBinding and HostListener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm currently migrating some ng 1.X element directive to the 1.5 "component" format.

My directives were all in "replace : true" mode, and a lot of them have stuff like "ng-class" or "ng-click" on the root element of the directive.

With the new .component() format, replace is forced to false (like in ng2). But in ng2, there is stuff like HostBinding and HostListener to interact with the component's root element.

What is the correct equivalent to HostBinding in ng1 components ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with `$element` and `$scope` controller local dependencies.

```
function SomeComponentController($scope, $element) {
  var self = this;

  $scope('$ctrl.foo', function (foo, oldFoo) {
    if (foo === oldFoo)
      return;

    // @HostBinding('bar') foo;
    self.bar = foo;

    // @HostBinding('attr.bar') foo;
    $element.attr('bar', foo);

    // @HostBinding('class.bar') foo;
    $element.toggleClass('bar', !!foo);
  });

  // @HostListener('click') onClick() {...}
  $element.on('click', function () {
    $scope.$evalAsync(self.onClick);
  });

  self.onClick = function () {...}.bind(self);
}
```

If you want to ease future transition from AngularJS to Angular, it should be noticed that [`ng-metadata`](https://github.com/ngParty/ng-metadata) is supposed to closely replicate Angular 2+ API in 1.x TypeScript projects.

It contains implementations of said decorators and also provides notes on what's going on under the hood:

[`@HostBinding`](http://@HostBinding)

> just creates $scope.$watch on provided controller property and changes the DOM by used type classname(toggleClass)/attribute(attr)/property(setPathValue)

[`@HostListener`](https://hotell.gitbooks.io/ng-metadata/content/docs/api/core/decorator.html#hostlistener)

> manually registers event listeners on host element via .on(eventName) and executes provided method within listener callback wrapped with #scope.$applyAsync() to notify whole app about possible changes

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that confirm that there is no proper equivalent.

Comment: You're welcome. I would call this a proper equivalent. When you write code this way with migration in mind, you can easily translate from 1.x to 2/4. And again, you can use ng-metadata for 1.x code that will require almost no changes during migration.